# Does MuleSoft support OpenAPI 3.x.x specification?

Tags: swagger, openapi, ibm-api-management

It is so confusing, can someone help me demystify? 
Does MuleSoft support OpenAPI 3.x.x specification as of today? Also what is this RAML 1.0 specification? Do we really care about RAML specs when dealing with MuleSoft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenAPI Specification (OAS), originally known as the Swagger Specification, is a specification for machine-readable interface files for describing, producing, consuming, and visualizing RESTful web services.

RAML, API Blueprint are same kind of IDL for REST API.

MuleSoft have a product called Anypoint Platform API designer that can help design only RAML API specifications, so it **does NOT support OAS 3.0.0**.

However, the product support the OAS 2.0. You can import an OAS ZIP or JSON file from your file system or from a URL. The importation converts the OAS to RAML. Basically, it is OAS to RAML converter.

Answer (score 1):

The OAS 3.x support has been released in MuleSoft in API Designer, Anypoint Exchange, and Anypoint API Community Manager since June 26, 2020.
You still can not use OAS 3.x in the implementation and manually have to convert it to RAML or OAS 2.0. But API consumers can still discover, learn, and consume the APIs seamlessly, regardless of the specification language.

More in this link. https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/platform/oas3

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. there is a latest release on OAS3.1.0 support in mule4.
Anypoint studio, designer, exchange supports new features such as callbacks and links.
If you want to migrate mule3 to mule4 use mule migration assistant.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/platform/oas3

Please have a look at it.